# `pred` of Char in List[Char]

Tags: scalaz

Looking at the well-written learning Scalaz, I looked at `Enum`'s:

```
scala> 'a' |-> 'e'
res20: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, d, e)
```

I can get its head:

```
scala> res20(0)
res21: Char = a
```

And then get its successor:

```
scala> res20(0).succ
res22: Char = b
```

But, why's the `pred` of the head equal to ```?

```
scala> res20(0).pred
res23: Char = `
```

And the same for the pred's pred equal to `_`?

```
scala> res20(0).pred.pred
res24: Char = _
```

Answer (score 2):

`Char` doesn't start at `a`. You'll see the same results for e.g. `('a' - 1).toChar`, which is essentially all `Enum`'s `pred` is doing (although in a more principled way, without the horrible automatic conversions from `Char` to `Int`).